# Removing Free-Spacing (whitespace and comments) from Regex

Tags: mysql, ruby, regex

I have a Ruby `Regexp` object that includes comments and whitespace (free-space mode), I'd like to manipulate it into MySQL-compatible (REGEXP) form.

Example:

```
r = /(?x)
      # Some comment
      example.com|
      subdomain.example.me
/
```

Desired resulting regex (without comments or whitespace):

```
/example.com|subdomain.example.me/
```

**More Context:**

I have a regex which has been build with the \x attribute to enable free-spacing mode. This mode ignores whitespace and comments in the regex.

I have a Regexp object build with the \x attribute, which works when used in ruby. However I'd like to use this regex in a mySQL 'REGEXP' query which doesn't support free-mode (to my knowledge).

Comment: Are you saying that you have a Ruby `Regexp` object that you need to programatically rewrite to a MySQL-compatible form?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm saying. I'll try reword to make it clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = /(?x)
      # Some comment
       example.com|
             subdomain.example.me
     /
        puts r     #=> (?x-mi:
                   #    # Some comment
                   #     example.com|
                   #          subdomain.example.me
                   #  )

        puts r.to_s.gsub(/#.*?\n|^\(\?x-mi:|\)$|\s/,"")   
                   #=>example.com|subdomain.example.me
```

limitation is no sharps in the new regex area.